# Serialize List of References

Tags: unity, c#, serialization

I have a list of object references inside a serializable class, like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class Test : MonoBehavior{
    public List<SomeSerializableObject> list;
}
```

When I instatiate a copy (with Instatiate()), the objects inside the list get copied and are no longer references to the original elements in the list.
Using `[SerializeReference]` only works for the list itself, but how do I do it for the items inside the list?

Comment: Can you help us understand what this list of references is pointing to? Are these items serialized anywhere else, or do some entries in the list point to the same item?

Comment: From my understanding the items in the list have to be proper Unity assets (with GUIDs) to be able to support serializable references. Otherwise a copy-by-value is the only thing that is possible via serialization.

Comment: @DMGregory Every item is unique. The objects are custom serializable classes, so non-unity objects.

Comment: @Charly So they need to inherit from ScriptableObject or MonoBehavior?

Comment: @DMGregory Each item is unique but not only referenced by this list, this is my problem. Sorry for articulating myself so poorly.

Comment: So, what we'll need you to do is edit your question so we can see all references to these items in context. There might be solutions for your use case, but to find good ones we need to understand that use case thoroughly — that includes knowing what this list is storing, where it's being used, and how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### The Problem

In [Unity's Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeReference.html) :

> - [Serialize] Referenced values **cannot** be shared between UnityEngine.Object instances. For example, two MonoBehaviours cannot share an object that is serialized by reference. Use ScriptableObjects instead to share data.

As Instantiate creates a new Unity Object, its data cannot be shared by reference by just decorating the fields with a [SerializeReference] Attributes.

##### The Solution

Instead, each member of the list that you want to be copied by reference during instantiation must be **it's own Unity Asset**. This means each member has to be inherit from UnityEngine.Object and be an actual Asset on disk with a .meta file with a GUID. It's these GUIDs which are the links which Unity's serialization system uses to stitch all the references back together at edit or runtime.

You can create an Unity asset via script by going AssetDatabase.CreateAsset([...]) with anything which inherits from UnityEngine.Object. But instead what you probably want to do for convenient sake is inherit from ScriptableObject and then create your assets via the asset menu (which you can open by right clicking in the project window). This way you can create new assets in the editor and don't have to create custom inspectors to edit their values.

Here are the two scripts which get the job done:

```
[CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "Custom/test so", order = 0)]
public class MySO : ScriptableObject
{
    public int Value;
}
```

And:

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<MySO> scriptableObjectAssets;
}
```

Opening the asset menue to create the scriptableObject:

[image: Opening the asset menu to create the SO]

The inspector for the the Monobehavior with the members which will be copied by reference during instantiations:

[image: The inspector for the Monobehavior with list members which will be copied by reference during Instantiates]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I made my list items inherit from ScriptableObject and use Object.CreateInstance to instantiate them.